# C# problem with restarting windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a reactJS application that called a backend API in C#. The API will check and restart the Windows Services if it is down. However, the performance does not seem to be consistent between each device. At some devices, the Windows Services is able to start and stop with no issue. Some devices it wont start until I restart the laptop. When I right click on my service and request 'Stop', I get this error message:

> Windows could not stop the XXX Services on Local Computer.
>
> Error 109: The pipe has been ended.

The services is stopped, but it won't auto restart.

This is the front-end function that is fetching the API:

```
checkWebService = () => {
    fetch(getAPIURL() + '/common/CheckWebService', {
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) { throw response }
        return response //we only get here if there is no error
    }).then(data => {
        console.log('restart web service data: ', data);
        this.setState({
            wsIsConnect: true,
        }, () => {
            this.doneLoading(false);
        });

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('restart web service err: ', err);
        this.setState({
            wsIsConnect: false,
        }, () => {
            this.doneLoading(true);
        });
    });
}
```

The API in C#:

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

//Activate the Windows Services if status it is stopped or pending
[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]    //ServiceController only allows in Windows
[HttpPost("CheckWebService")]
public string CheckWebService()
{
    try
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(ServiceName);

        Debug.WriteLine("checkwebservice status" + service.Status);

        if ((service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) || (service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))
            service.Start();

        return "success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log("Error", ex.ToString(), "CheckWebService");

        return ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds more like a problem with that specific service and less with the code that tries to start/stop that service. Trying to start when stopping is pending seems wrong tho.

Comment: Noted on that. I've changed the StopPending to pause instead.